# Select Dates with no result Php/MySql

Tags: mysql, date

I'm trying to get value of fields from a table from a date-range in `Php/Mysql`. I am getting results for which record exists but if there is no record in date in between I am not getting any result for the particular date as its skipped. All I want is to get 0 for all fields where data is not available for date range.

Query:

```
//select data for 90 days
SELECT stats_user_id,user_id,views_count,saved_count,
    inquiry_count,date,status,click_count,inquiry_replied_count,
    DATE_FORMAT(date,'%a') as x_key 
from mecars_stats_user 
where user_id = 59  
AND date >= '2017-04-15' 
AND date <= '2017-05-14' 
ORDER BY stats_user_id
```

Or

```
//Select data for 3 years 
SELECT stats_user_id,user_id,views_count,saved_count,
        inquiry_count,date,status,click_count,inquiry_replied_count,
        DATE_FORMAT(date,'%y') as x_key 
from mecars_stats_user 
where user_id = 59  
AND date >= DATE_ADD(date, -3, GETDATE())  
GROUP BY YEAR(date) 
ORDER BY stats_user_id
```

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code.

Comment: yes you are right but the API is complex enough to handle different types of date ranges like day ranges , month ranges yearly ranges and decades etc so it will be very expensive to move across application logic thats why i was searching some SQL based solution

Comment: Well, using where clause in main table it will show only those records which are perfect for conditions. If not as per condition it will not be in result set. 
For showing 0 if not as per date range, you need to do some condition in code level.

Comment: @MehvishFaisal if you want to do in SQL level, (as you mentioned in your comment) maybe you can do self-join and then fulfill your need.

Comment: thanks @NaveedRamzan I m just getting into it lets see where it ends up

Comment: @MehvishFaisal Ok great. do let me know if you done with it.

Comment: @NaveedRamzan Did it in application logic

Comment: @MehvishFaisal: That's nice.